# PHP rounding issue

Tags: php, sql, rounding-error

I am getting a rounding issues, I have a database of 3 charities with different amounts.. then in the front I have the 3 charities displaying there percentage based on the amount assigned to them and the total percentage always needs to add to 100%.. currently if each charity has 1 assigned to it, it displays 33% on each which equals 99% where i need to cheat it in a way to always be equal to 100%..

Here is the PHP

```
$charity = $_POST['charity'];
$sql = "SELECT amount FROM charities";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $total += $row['amount'];
}

$sql_individual = "SELECT * FROM charities WHERE charity='$charity'";
$result_individual = mysqli_query($con, $sql_individual);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_individual)) {
    $charity = $row['amount'];
}

echo round($charity / $total * 100,0) . "%";
```

I found a maths solution for this.. but.. my maths isn't all that great.. but.. okay in all honesty i do not understand this fully:

```
c = 100 - (a + b) - e,g 34 = 100 - (33 + 33)
```

any Help Greatly Appreciated..

Comment: What would you want to display?

Comment: as explained above, each charity gets a percentage based on the amount assigned to them ($charity / $total * 100,0) but.. well i need the sum of the charity always to equal 100%, and currently if each charity has an amount of 1 the sum of all of them equals 99%

Comment: Maybe you can try [ceil()](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.ceil.php). It works 'like' round().

Comment: Hey thanks Katona.. tried but got even weirder results.. like 101%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no rounding issues, You just round to an integer numbers, that means that if You have 5 values like these:

1. 12,25%
2. 13,25%
3. 20,25%
4. 30,25%
5. 34,00%

after using `round($x, 0)` on them they will be rounded to these values:

1. 12
2. 13
3. 20
4. 30
5. 34

After summing these rounded values You get the value of **99**.

It is best to round at least to two decimal places when working with percentages - and only for displaying purposes. You shouldn't round any values that will be used for further math operation...

Comment: That's why he needs to cheat as stated in the question :-)

Comment: @FrédéricClausset And that's why I am tending on rounding percentage values to at least 2 decimal places when printing the values out to the user... ;-)